# In laravel Getting error : The "https://packagist.laravel-china.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to `composer update` in my project,i am getting error `The "https://packagist.laravel-china.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded`, I took git clonse from this URL   `https://github.com/ssrpanel/SSRPanel` , can anyone please help me how to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
composer clear-cache
```

then

```
composer -vvv
composer dump-autoload
```

after that try running the install/update command for laravel, it worked for me though